# Im using generics in java to find the maximum value of an array but it only accepts Double data type but not other data types

Tags: java, generics

```
@Override
public Double max() {
    Double total = (Double)super.array[0];
    for(T t : super.array) {
        if (t == null) {
            continue;
        }
        else if (t instanceof Number) {
            Number n = (Number)t;
            if(total < n.doubleValue()) {
                total = n.doubleValue();
            }
        }
        else if(t instanceof INumber) {
            INumber n = (INumber)t;
            if(total < n.getNumber()) {
                total = n.getNumber();
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
```

Im using generics in java to find the maximum value of an array but it only accepts Double data type but not other data types please help I know the problem is (Double) cast so how do i resolve this

Comment: The general way to compare objects in Java is if they implement the `Comparable` interface, which documents how to compare one object to another.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop body already correctly checks the type of each element.  So use that logic to initialize your `total`, by setting `total` to null initially:

```
Double total = null;
```

Then you can check for null in your loop:

```
for (T t : super.array) {
    if (t == null) {
        continue;
    }
    else if (t instanceof Number) {
        Number n = (Number)t;
        if (total == null || total < n.doubleValue()) {
            total = n.doubleValue();
        }
    }
    else if(t instanceof INumber) {
        INumber n = (INumber)t;
        if (total == null || total < n.getNumber()) {
            total = n.getNumber();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first line `Double total = (Double)super.array[0];`, you have cast the element to a Double. So any other type will throw an exception, this is definitely not what you want.

In fact if you want to get the max element of an array, the element must implements `Comparable` interface. You can do like this:

```
<T extends Comparable<T>> T getMax(T[] array){
        T max=null;
        for (T t : array) {
            if (max==null) max=t;
            else {
                max=max.compareTo(t)>0?max:t;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
```